# Dispatch event from child to grandparent in Svelte

Tags: javascript, events, event-handling, svelte

The structure of my application is as follows:

- Grandparent is a form
- Parent is an input which calls an api
- Child displays the results of the api call

In the child component I want to pass data up to the Grandparent, depending on which result the user clicks on. I tried doing this, using an [Event Dispatcher](https://svelte.dev/docs#createEventDispatcher). This unfortunately fails, as it seems that communication is only possible between parent and child. Is there a way to accomplish this?

This here is my (simplified) code:

```
// Grandparent
  <form on:submit|preventDefault={handleSubmit}>
    <Search bind:item={item} on:result={e => console.log(e)} />
  </form>

// Parent
   <div class="search-results">
      <Response data={res} />
   </div>

// Child
  <script>
    function returnData(data) {
      dispatch("result", data);
    }
  </script>

  <button on:click={() => returnData(data)}>Click</button>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can bubble events by using `on:<eventName>` without any event handler afterwards:

```html
// Grandparent
  <form on:submit|preventDefault={handleSubmit}>
    <Search bind:item={item} on:result={e => console.log(e)} />
  </form>

// Parent
   <div class="search-results">
      <!-- only this line changes in your code:
           bubble the result event -->
      <Response data={res} on:result />
   </div>

// Child
  <script>
    function returnData(data) {
      dispatch("result", data);
    }
  </script>

  <button on:click={() => returnData(data)}>Click</button>
```

Comment: So I need the `on:result` handler here and and in the Grandparent, or? The parrent will just pass the event on then?

Comment: @Gh05d `on:result` (with no callback) in the parent, `on:result={() => { /* your code here */ }}` in the grandparent